# Convert text string to any valid Ruby formatted time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following date string "Monday 31 January".

Is there any way to convert that to a valid Ruby formatted time so I can convert it to something else?

---

How could I parse it in the case that it was in a different language, for instance in Spanish "Lunes 31 Enero"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How could I parse it in the case that it was in a different language, i.e. Spanish "Lunes 31 Enero"?

Normally I'd say go with the [Chronic gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/) as your best bet for flexible date time parsing. Tossing in different languages makes it a different problem, because the libraries are geared toward English.

That means falling back to `Date.parse`. Dropping into IRB I had a surprise:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > puts Date.parse('Lunes 31 Enero')
2011-01-31
```

So, Date.parse is already Spanish-saavy.

If it wasn't, it might be possible to override Date's Month and Day constants to give it a helping hand:

```
require 'date'

Date::MONTHNAMES      = [nil] + %w( Enero Febrero Marzo Abril Mayo Junio Julio Agosto Septiembre Octubre Noviembre Diciembre )
Date::DAYNAMES        = %w( Lunes Martes Miércoles Jueves Viernes Sábado Domingo )
Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES = [nil] + %w( Ene Feb Mar Abr May Jun Jul Ago Sep Oct Nov Dic )
Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES   = %w( Lun Mar Mié Jue Vie Sáb Dom )
```

I haven't tested that, since it already works without messing with things, but for other, non-supported, languages, it might be a worthwhile experiment to change the values and see what happens.

Comment: I know this is a really old post but I just tried `Date.parse('Lunes 31 Enero')` with Ruby 2.3 and it no longer works. The only reason why it works for certain months like `marzo` is because the first three characters are `mar` and that matches with `mar` from `march`

Comment: You might want to check into "[Ruby International Date Parser](https://gist.github.com/jackrg/2927162)" and/or [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic). Otherwise it shouldn't be hard to map the day/month names to english equvalents.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.parse` works just fine:

```
$ irb
>> d = Date.parse('Monday 31 January')
=> #<Date: 4911185/2,0,2299161>
>> d.year
=> 2011
>> d.month
=> 1
>> d.day
=> 31
```

Comment: Thank you, I added something I forgot to the original question about different language parsing of date.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "Monday 31 January"
date = Date.parse(string)
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like `Date.parse(string)` will work for you. When given your example string, it returns `Mon, 31 Jan 2011` as a Date object.

Comment: Works fine in irb, without rails loaded.

Comment: On ruby 1.9.2p136, `Date#parse` doesn't exist, and raises an error to that effect.

Comment: "On ruby 1.9.2p136, Date#parse doesn't exist". It does, you just have to `require 'date'`. "this is Rails only". No, you have to require the library.